# Inbox pause feature email app

Tags: productivity, email-client

Are there any Linux apps for email for apps with add-ones with an Inbox Pause feature or even a Inbox Window feature?

By Inbox Pause, I mean a mode in which incoming email isn’t displayed until I press unpause. To allow me to focus on other tasks and existing email I’m writing or reading.

By Inbox Windows, I mean set time periods during the day when new mail will show in my Inbox. E.g., suppose I wish to deal with new email only between 3 and 4 PM each day. At all other days, I don’t want new mails to arrive.

Answer (score 1):

Both evolution and thunderbird have a "Work Offline" option on their File menu (inside an Offline submenu for thunderbird).

Having the mail client (MUA) configured to Work Offline make it not to connect to the network (thus not receiving mails), while having the program open so that you can work with it (otherwise, not opening the email client at all would be the obvious solution).

Note that if you are using an IMAP account it will work with the messages it has cached locally, so you would probably want to ensure that received messages are downloaded for offline use.

If you are connecting with a classic POP approach, a much simpler option would be to simply configure the MUA not to automatically download mail, requiring you to explicitly request that it downloads new messages. This is also possible to an extent with an IMAP account, but it will still refresh the mailbox automatically in some cases (typically, when switching folders) and thus, it may either be acceptable for you or not.